# Permalink Issue | Too many redirects

Tags: permalinks

I'm having an issue which I haven't come across before. I created a page with the same title as another existing page and as standard it gave it a -2 to the permalink for the new page so permalink "page-2".

Then I deleted the existing page with permalink "page" and deleted from trash. I then changed the permalink of the "page-2" to "page" and now I'm getting a ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS in chrome.

I've done this many times before without issue and have tried flushing the permalinks, but it doesn't seem to be working. It's a multisite, not sure if this would have any bearing on it.

It's when I try to access "page" it redirects to "page-2" and vice versa.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Someone might know specifically what the problem is, but to help diagnose, can you share the URL of the page? Using a tool like curl you might be able to see which pages are in the redirect loop if the redirect is client side.

Comment: Thanks, just checked and it's a 301 redirect loop on just that page